# Having trouble having text appear inside div that appears on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with having text showing all the time that is nested inside a div that only appears on hover. I have attempted to research this issue and none of the fixes I have tried seem to want to work. I've tried both `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`/`display:block` on the code. I have also tried implementing the  solution by using `#color-overlay:hover + #color-overlay{}` My goal is to have the plus sign hidden and have it appear with #color-overlay when someone mouses over any part of the card (not just the plus sign itself).

```css
#book-card {
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/book.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#color-overlay{
    width: 350px;
   height: 500px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -250px 0 0 -175px;
   display: none;
 }

#color-overlay:hover{
    background: rgba(139,0,0,0.8);
    transition: background 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
}

#plus {
    font-size: 70px;
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 41%;
}
```

```html
<div id="book-card">
    <div id="color-overlay">
        <p id="plus">+</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use `display:none` #color-overlay no longer changes on hover and doesn't want to show up again. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `opacity` for that like this

```css
#book-card {
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/book.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#color-overlay{
    width: 350px;
   height: 500px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -250px 0 0 -175px;
   opacity: 0;
 }

#color-overlay:hover{
    background: rgba(139,0,0,0.8);
    transition: background 0.4s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}

#plus {
    font-size: 70px;
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 41%;
}
```

```html
<div id="book-card">
    <div id="color-overlay">
        <p id="plus">+</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of that solution! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change this CSS

```
#color-overlay{
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -175px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
 }

#color-overlay:hover{
    background: rgba(139,0,0,0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of that solution! I appreciate your help.